# В чем разница между «сестрёнка» и «сестрица»?

Tags: выбор-слов, синонимы

«Сестрёнка» и «сестрица» – уменьшительно-ласкательные слова от «сестра».

Интересно, чем по смыслу и употреблению одно отличается от другого?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начнём с того, что "сестрица" и "сестрёнка" отличаются не только стилистически, но и семантически. Это не полные синонимы, совпадают только в одном значении - именно как ласкательное к сестра.

Кузнецов, правда, это общее значение разделяет на два - для прямого и переносного значений, но суть от этого не меняется.

> СЕСТРЁНКА, -и; мн. род. -нок, дат. -нкам; ж. Разг. 1. Ласк. к Сестра
>   (1 зн.). 2. Маленькая сестра. Смотреть за сестрёнкой. Уложить
>   сестрёнку. 3. Ласково-фамильярное обращение к любой посторонней
>   женщине (обычно одного возраста, или медсестре). Помоги, с. С., где
>   тут Кузьмичёвы живут, не подскажешь? С., перевяжи. <Сестрёнкин, -а,
>   -о. Чья дача? - С. С-ы подружки. С сестрёнкиной подсказки и женился.
>
> СЕСТРИЦА, -ы; ж. 1. Ласк. =Сестра (1, 3 зн.). Лисица-сестрица
>   (нар.-поэт.; в русских сказках: устойчивый эпитет лисы). 2. =Сестрёнка
>   (3 зн.). С., будь другом, добеги до аптеки. С., дай снотворного.
>   <Сестрицын, -а, -о. Сестрицыных рук дело! Только сестрицыными
>   молитвами и выжил. А сумка-то с-а.

Отсюда понятно, что, скажем, **медицинскую сестру** правильно будет ласкательно назвать ***сестрицей***, но не *сестренкой*. Напротив, **маленькую сестру** чтобы подчеркнуть её возраст лучше назвать **сестрёнкой**.

Что же касается общего, уменьшительно-ласкательного значения этих слов, то я бы сказал, что **сестрица** скорее ласкательное, а **сестрёнка** - уменьшительное. Кроме того, **сестрица** сейчас больше свойственно народно-поэтической речи, в быту превалирует **сестрёнка**.